# Eclipse deletes closing parenthesis

Tags: eclipse

The following steps show typing into the eclipse Java editor.

```
mock(  // I type this into Eclipse
mock(|) // Eclipse automatically adds the closing parenthesis, the | is my caret
mock(String.class|) // I fill out a class name, and an autocomplete window is shown.
mock(String.class); // I finish the statement by typing ");"
```

After I type ");", Eclipse magically deletes the parenthesis, leaving me with

```
mock(String.class;
```

This is extremely frustrating. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600
```